# Module not found "../aws-exports"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, yaml, aws-amplify

I am attempting to build on Amplify hosting, and am facing a front-end build issue. I am using **Next.js**.

**Error:**

```
./src/pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../aws-exports' in  '/codebuild/output/src195962774/src/PROJECTNAME/src/pages'
```

**amplify.yml file:**

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install 
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install 
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
```

I have tried a variety of combinations for this build file, and moved away of the initial issue with [graphql-ttl-transformer](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/606).

I have also tried copying a duplicate to the pages folder, and trying again. I am using VsCode, so the file-path of `"../aws-exports"` is correct, as it was auto-populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to pull in a different backend app in your frontend project? If yes then backend part of your build script should have a command to pull in that project.

aws-exports.json file gets generated during the backend build phase.

Just to prove this you may try commiting and pushing your local aws exports file (it is git ignored by default).

If that works then modify your backend script to pull the amplify backend project. Something like `amplify pull --appId YOUR_APP_ID --envName YOUR_ENV_NAME`